# scolling the pop-up box without scrolling the web page behind it

Tags: html, css, popup, scrollbar

now I have a simple custom pop-up box and its overlay background that covers all the web page behind it (height:100%, width:100%). my question is how can I make the scoll bar only scroll the pop-up box and its background not the page behind them.

Thanks. sorry for my english.

Comment: like in twitter for example, when I open up a profile summary of other person the right sroll bar only scrolling the profile summary window not the web page behind it. now, how can i do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a css for the pop-up box

overflow:scroll; //for both vertical and horizontal bar
overflow-x:scroll; //for horizontal bar
overflow-y:scroll; //for vertical bar

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), you can find some help